# Doubt in non-blocking statement verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, hdl

**Suppose i have 2 non-blocking statements as follows:**

```
    reg x,y;

    initial
    
    begin
    
    x=10; 
    
    y=20;
    
    end
```

**and if I execute this:**
**a)**

```
always @(posedge clk)

x<=y;

always @(posedge clk)

y<=x;
```

**So will the values of x and y get swapped or will there be race condition here? (suppose i print the values in the 2 blocks, right after the assignment). Also will the always blocks run independent of each other?
and what's the difference if I do this:
b)**

```
always @(posedge clk)

begin

x<=y;

y<=x;

end
```

Comment: Both are same. It will infer two flip flops like a circular shift register shifting values at clockedge.. In simulation, it will have initial values as in the initial block.

Comment: What do you think will happen? There are many similar questions on this site, have you looked through them?

Answer (score 0):

The two pieces of code are identical in simulation and synthesis; their values will be swapped. Assignments to `x` and `y` use their current RHS values and the order of assignments does not matter because the LHS updates happen after both statements have completed.

If you were to print the the values right after the assignment like

```
always @(posedge clk) begin

                      x<=y;
                      $display("x ",x);
                      end

always @(posedge clk) begin
                      y<=x;
                      $display("y ",y);
                      end
```

Then there is a race as to which `$display` statement you will see first, but both will print the current values of `x` and `y`, not their updated values.